# How can I modify ActiveAdmin redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working within active admin to have an admin dashboard for my model - however when i go to localhost:3000/admin/login and login I get redirected to localhost:3000 instead of being pointed to localhost3000/admin/dashboard.

How can I adjust this? - Tried modifying the load path to

```
  config.load_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, "admin", "dashboard")]
```

I also checked my routes and I think the crux of it is that my rails root is / but I mean , shouldn't it be for any other user on the site?

Thanks for any clarification !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `devise` routes in the `config/routes.rb` file, you can pass some options:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

`ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` looks something like this:

```
{
 :path=>:admin,
 :controllers=>
  {:sessions=>"active_admin/devise/sessions",
   :passwords=>"active_admin/devise/passwords",
   :unlocks=>"active_admin/devise/unlocks",
   :registrations=>"active_admin/devise/registrations",
   :confirmations=>"active_admin/devise/confirmations"},
 :path_names=>{:sign_in=>"login", :sign_out=>"logout"},
 :sign_out_via=>[:delete, :get]
}
```

The `:path=>:admin` option in this case tells `devise` that `/admin` is the root path.

Check this in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't been totally aware of that - My devise routes are quite simplistic right now.